# Scala, Cats, Intellij IDEA: fix syntax & compile errors?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-cats

Using the Cats library for Scala in IntelliJ IDEA leads to errors even if terminal SBT works. Can we fix this? Or some workaround that isn't switching editor?

Comment: this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695616/false-errors-when-using-cats-library-in-intellij

Answer (score 5):

Cats seems to work fine on my IntelliJ 2018.1.4. If it is working in the terminal but not in IntelliJ, it could be because of using in-built IntelliJ compiler. Have you tried enabling [`Use sbt shell for build and import`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#run_sbt_scala_app), which delegates building to SBT:

1. Open sbt projects tool window: `View | Tool Windows | sbt`
2. Click `sbt settings` icon
3. Select `Use sbt shell for build and import (required sbt 0.13.5+)`

`Use sbt shell` might resolve compilation issues, however note that in-editor error highlighting might still give false positives because it uses custom-built typechecker.

---

<sub>[Metals](https://scalameta.org/metals/) is an alternative that uses Scala proper for both compilation and in-editor error diagnostics.</sub>

Comment: Good improvement, thanks! Can we also somehow fix syntax highlighting and "live" error reporting? (intellij's sidebar errors)

Comment: Try, from the main menu, `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

Comment: After invalidatin caches / restart, IntelliJ still will report errors unfortunately :(

Comment: @ticofab Try the nuke option, where you `rm -fr .idea` and re-import the project.

Comment: I was tackling this issue for hours now, and then I updated my IDE from 2017 to 2018 + used the ```Use sbt shell...``` option -- This solved all my issues and now all my red squiggly lines are gone + my autocomplete works. :)